# Jupyter-notebook ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ranger'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have read the similar questions in stackoverflow, but it's still be the weird issue in my Jupyter-notebook.

I have write this code

```
import sys  
!{sys.executable} -m pip install --user ranger
```

and the result is

```
Requirement already satisfied: ranger in c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.10)
```

But, when I used the library

```
from ranger import Ranger
```

It's still give me the error information ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ranger'

Is there any another solution?
Thank you.

> For Information. Jupyter Python 3.7, Pip 20.0.2

Answer (score 1):

try `from Ranger import Range`

the class in the package is called Range

Comment: still the same bro

Comment: this is strange. have you tried to import the other class (Cut) which comes with the package?